# How can I use the Geolocation API in Firefox (local development)?

Tags: firefox, https, geolocation

I'm writing an application that uses the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API). One of the requirements of this API is that it must be used over HTTPS.

The following shell script shows the process that I've been following for setting up HTTPS for localhost:

```
echo "Started local certificate setup script."

# Generate a private 2048-bit RSA key and encrypt it using triple DES before outputting it
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048

# Create a root CA public certificate
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 825 -out rootCA.pem

# Create a new certificate signing request (CSR) and a new private key
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -config server.csr.cnf

# Using the previously generated CSR, and the root CA cert, generate a server.crt which will be the certificate file we use for localhost
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 825 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext

echo "Trust the root certificate (add it to the system keychain): "
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain rootCA.pem # macOS specific step
```

The starting files in the above OpenSSL commands are here:

`v3.ext`:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid, issuer
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

`server.csr.cnf`:

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
C=CA
ST=RandomProvince
L=RandomCity
O=RandomOrganization
OU=RandomOrganizationUnit
emailAddress=admin@whatever.com
CN = localhost
```

This works perfectly for doing local development work in Chrome (currently on version 83.0.4103.116). We can see that we get a self signed root certificate and Chrome trusts it:

[image]

Chrome also trusts the localhost certificate which uses this root CA that we've created for local development:

[image]

However, there are times when I'd like to also run locally using Firefox. Whenever I'm using Firefox I get the following: `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER`. I can get past this error in Firefox by using `about:config` and then turning `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` to `true`. At this point Firefox doesn't complain at all about the certificate - but all requests for the user location result in permission denied errors.

Even clicking "Allow Location Access" in the following pop-up results in the geolocation API thowing an error saying that permission was denined to access the user location:

[image]

I'm using the following function to get the location (context argument since it's in a Vue.js project using Vuex):

```
findCurrentPosition(context) {
    const options = {
      timeout: 20000,
      enableHighAccuracy: false,
      maximumAge: Infinity,
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            const lat = position.coords.latitude
            const lon = position.coords.longitude
            setLocation(context, [lat, lon])
            resolve([lat, lon])
          },
          error => {
            switch (error.code) {
              case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                console.log('User denied the request for Geolocation.') // in Firefox, even after explicitly allowing location access, this is always hit
                break
              case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
              case error.TIMEOUT:
              case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                // get location another way
            }
            reject([])
          },
          options,
        )
      } else {
        // get location another way
      }
    })
  }
```

How can I use the geolocation API in Firefox while doing local development? I have disabled all Firefox extensions in order to exclude the possibility that one of them is interfering with getting the location.